# Linear Algebra : Some Good Books for Eigenvalue, Eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, book-recommendation, diagonalization

Can Anyone tell me which is the best books for diagonalization, Eigenvalue & Eigenvector?
I am Preaparing for CSIR-NET, GATE, TIFR Exams..
There are many Good Books but if you can tell me about two good books only, it will be very helpful.

Comment: I think every book is basically the same. It is a preference of style of author which makes you prefer one over the other. Topic wise it is everywhere the same, really. A good introduction to linear algebra is "Linear Algebra done right" by Sheldon Axler. If you like it, or it fits your bill, I can not tell. Also this book is not specific or special about Eigenvalues, or Eigenvectors. It is just another chapter. I do not think there are books which cover these topics more thoroughly.

Comment: Thank You For Your Suggestion..

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can ask questions for reference books to study some object or topic as curiosity.

But, it is not good to post reference-question for competitive exams.

Anyway

Here are two references, which I found better. Since the number of books on Linear Algebra or Matrices is so huge, my choice may not be very good.

But, I enjoyed them (an enjoy today also) when I read any topic in it, considering that the author is speaking the sentences; it gives feeling of lecture.

[Linear Algebra by Kwak, Jin Ho, Hong, Sungpyo](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780817642945)

[Linear Algebra: Charles Curtis](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387909929)

One remark: the best thing to learn any topic in mathematics is by solving problems. It is better to **Try to solve** problems, by referring any book, rather than choosing a particular guide-type book.